# How do I add xmlName attribute to a field in BeanIO using Java?

Tags: java, xml, bean-io

I am trying to add xmlName attribute to a field in my mapping file. Now I know I can add xmlName attribute to any field by adding it manually, but I want to know if it is possible to add it using Java code.

Here is my mapping.xml file:

```
beanio>

  <stream name="employees" format="xml">
    <record name="employee" class="example.Employee">
      <field name="firstName" />
      <field name="lastName" />
      <field name="title" />
      <field name="salary" />
      <field name="hireDate" type="date" />
    </record>
  </stream>
  
</beanio>
```

In the above file, I want to set xmlName attribute for my field firstName as fName. I have looked through BeanIO documentation, but I did not see any method that would help me add xmlName attribute using Java. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to [BuilderApiAndAnnotations](http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/reference/index.html#BuilderApiAndAnnotations) and add xmlName attribute by [FieldBuilder#xmlName(String xmlName)](http://beanio.org/2.1/docs/api/org/beanio/builder/PropertyBuilderSupport.html#xmlName-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the question, but could you please provide an example on how to implement it to read/update the file?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add xmlName attribute to the mapping file by java code, why?

Comment: I want to create data using that XML mapping file, so if I do not update that file and add xmlName attribute using java, then in the data it will have the name of that tag from code?

Comment: I do not want to add into it, but how do I create data using the mapping file and then use the xmlName attribute set in the code

Comment: I know how to create data using mapping file. I need your help because I'm going to read the same mapping file, but then for some field I will be using a different field name(xmlName) that I will define in the code. I need an example on how to set xmlName for a field inside the code. I do not want to update the mapping file, but I need to update the data that it is being created using the mapping file.